# Struts 2 Message Resource look-up issue

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, localization

I have a webserver with Struts 2.3 (with the conventions plugin)

I'm encountering some problems with the handling of `MessageResources` for localization.
This is my directory layout (simplified):

- *global.properties*
- **it.group.projectName**

  - **actions**

    - LoginAction.java
    - *LoginAction.properties*
    - **users**

      - SampleAction.java
      - *SampleAction.properties*
      - package-info.java (neesed for the conventions plugin to define namespace)
      - *package.properties*

**Package-info.java:**

```
@org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.ParentPackage(value = "users") 

package it.group.projectName.actions.users;
```

Now, if I ask for a string contained in `global.properties` or `LoginAction.properties` (using `<s:text name="navbar.myPage"/>` ) everything works fine.

But when I ask for any string contained in `package.properties` or `SampleAction.properties` from the page corresponding to `SampleAction` (`sample.jsp`) it seems it can't find it and just prints out the key. Any ideas?

According to [this](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-resource-bundle-example/) article (and others) Struts2 should load those files, but it seems to have some problems with convention plugin and the namespace redefinition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to that article you should read it careful. Another approach to get message resources is to use `getText`. Make sure the current locale is default and an action extends `ActionSupport`.

```
<s:property value="getText('navbar.myPage')" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the ActionSupport part :)

Comment: for everyone else, who got confused like me. The solution is to extend `ActionSupport`. Using `s:property` or `s:text` is just a matter of choice/requirement.